# Burn this Shirt

Tags: motto

I'm looking for a good 3 word (2 word would work as well) translation for:

### **Burn this Shirt**

The idea for the expression is to *set fire to the shirt or tunic that you're currently wearing* and make that action into a latin motto. I am new to Latin so I'm not sure where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To make it specifically refer to the shirt someone is wearing, you might want something more explicit in Latin like "burn your shirt" rather than "burn this shirt".

Comment: Latin also has a number of verbs that might work depending on the context of "burn", i.e. simply setting it on fire, burning it completely to ashes, just being affected by heat, etc. Did you have a more specific thought about what "burn" means in this context?

Comment: Thank you Adam for welcoming me!  "Burn your Shirt" would be perfect. And burn meaning catching the shirt on fire to the point of only ashes are left.  No harm to any person, just the shirt is burned to ashes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Where to start?

First, with a word for “burn.” The most general word is *uro*; however, in this case *comburo* (burn up, burn completely) is more fitting.

Next, “shirt” is [always a bit difficult to translate](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh22862), but as you suggested “tunic” yourself, let's go with *tunica*. (Attempts to find a more accurate translation usually concentrate on the “undergarment” aspect, but I doubt you're all that interested in that.)

Now we just take the imperative form of the verb, put the noun in the accusative case, add a demonstrative adjective, and we get:

> Combure istam tunicam.

Where English has “this” and “that,” Latin has a somewhat confusing selection of *is, hic, ille, iste*. I chose *iste* here, which we generally use when referring to something that is closer (in mind or in reality) to the listener than the speaker. “Burn the shirt you are wearing” sounds like that would be the case. Although I would really expect to hear “Burn that shirt” in that case. “Burn **this** shirt” sounds more like the motto is printed on the shirt, in which case you would say:

> Combure hanc tunicam.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastian_Koppehel for your very comprehensive explanation for this motto.  It's exactly what I was looking for on this site.

Comment: @Greg Glad to help. Note *comburo* is the root of our modern “combustion.” I also like to joke that *uro* is the root word of “urology,” but sadly, that's not really true …

Answer (score 19):

Sebastian's suggestion is perfect but just as an alternative, you could consider

> Tunica comburenda est!

This is literally "the shirt must be burned", but for the amusement of Roman history geeks, it's framed as an echo of Cato's famous catchphrase *[Carthago delenda est](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est)* "Carthage must be destroyed".

Comment: I would still add an *ista* to make it clear that the shirt is not referring to some other shirt. Also it has a nicer metre.

Comment: Or just `Tunica comburenda`

Comment: I am amazed at the helpfulness of this community.  Thank you, everyone, so much for your thorough assistance on this project.  

This is the design so far:  [link](https://bit.ly/3T5foK1)

Comment: @Greg Note though that the verb should be *combure*, not *combuste*.

Comment: @TKR Thanks!  Noted & changed.

Comment: +1, even though the other answer is a more literal translation, the passive periphrastic (formal name for this construction) is immediately recognizable to folks who forgot 90% of the Latin they used to know.  To that end, may I also suggest "inflammanda" (meaning "set on fire" rather than "burn up") since the root is more recognizable